# Web projects via Folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have to develop large system using ASP.NET with multi modules. What is the best practice of designing it? Is it be divide the modules to folders in the same web project or divide them to separated web projects in  the same solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a project containing more than 500 aspx pages, we used a single web project, a data connection layer project, a dataaccess project and a business layer project.

The web project is divided into multiple folders also containing sub folders.

The result is a very fast running asp.net project. Also, opening the project in Visual Studio takes only a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Project, Folders, Solution Folders and even Solutions (where necessary) can be used to divide large system into readable, easy to understand logical blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing it into folders is better as it would maintain the simplicity of your project.
less references is proportional to faster loading time.